# how to detect rmqr code (Rectangular Micro QR Code ) in image by python?

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I looking for some solution which detect Rectangular Micro QR Code in image.

General qr code is not problem. But I made rMQR (ISO/IEC 23941:2022(e)) code by qmqrcode from git.
(details are here https://github.com/OUDON/rmqrcode-python )

I tried zbar, qreader on python but those are failed.

```py
# pyzbar

import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
img=cv2.imread("rmqrcode_10000018.png")
decoded_objects = pyzbar.decode(img)
decoded_objects # result is []
```

```py
# qreader

## Create a QReader instance
qreader = QReader()

## Get the image that contains the QR code
image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("rmqrcode_10000018.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

## Use the detect_and_decode function to get the decoded QR data
decoded_text = qreader.detect_and_decode(image=image)
decoded_text # result is (None,)
```